# Install apk on Termux and wait for it to finish OR check whether apk is installed

Tags: android, apk, termux

In Termux I am installing several apk's using

`xdg-open myapp.apk`

and I want to make sure it actually happens, ie that the resulting install window doesn't disappear and ideally that the user was successful (chose to install it).  Instead, my script immediately continues, leaving the installation to go on in the background and maybe not happen.

I would like to ask the OS whether the app is installed, or have it complete the installation before continuing.

Comment: This situation has become much worse after a mandatory Android update this month. Now, launching .apk files with xdg-open makes some thing flash up and immediately disappear, with no installation done. Thus there is now seemingly no way even to initiate an installation from Termux.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How to check if APK is installed: *if device is rooted* - `tsudo pm list packages | grep my.package.id`
How to install APK - *if device is rooted*: `tsudo pm install mypackage.apk`
(you will need to install `tsudo` beforehand).

For non-rooted devices it is seemingly impossible to know if certain app is installed - most likely for security reasons.

Installing on non-rooted devices works with `xdg-open`, but *only* after you permit installing from untrusted sources in Android preferences for Termux app. **And** Termux should be active for it to work. (Termux-floating window or SSH won't work, unless main Termux window is active.)

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can check if an application is installed without root, first you need the file manager zarchiver, then you go to the /data/app directory through the arrow at the top of the folders, and here you will see a directory list, each of them have the icon of an app that you have installed, you will search for the one that have the icon of the app you want to check if installed, copy the directory name, and finally to check, in termux check if the directory "/data/app/directory name you copied" exists

Comment: I think the OP wants a solution they can run in a script instead of manually checking if an app is installed